# How to convert video to GIF using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, gif

I installed FFmpeg on my XAMPP for converting stream of video to GIF images.

I used the below code but it doesn't work.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05.0 -t 00:00:10.0 -i input.wmv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 output.gif
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is: You cannot simply copy the input video and audio streams to a GIF. GIFs need to be encoded differently. Basically you're telling FFmpeg to actually not convert anything.

Try this instead:

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i input.wmv -t 10 -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif
```

Notes:

- I shortened the timestamps. If you just need seconds, it's enough to specify those.
- `-t` is an output option and should go between `-i` and your output file name.
- GIFs need an RGB pixel format, which you have to specify as well.
- You may need to downscale your video so the GIF doesn't become unnecessarily large. Try adding `-filter:v "scale=-1:320"` or similar to downscale the output to 320 pixels height (and adjust the width automatically (`-1`).

<sub>Tip: "It doesn't work" is not a specific enough problem description. Please always include the full, uncut FFmpeg command output when asking FFmpeg questions.</sub>

Comment: thanks its works :) you save my life :) but it seems blurred image how can i get the gif image as like as video

Comment: You probably can't. GIFs were never meant to be used for video. Why would you want the videos to be GIFs in the first place, if I may ask?